What would happen to a soap bubble if there were no surface tension?
Suppose you have a soap bubble. Now, suppose that the surface tension in the liquid film that surrounds the bubble disappears instantly. What would happen to the bubble? Also, is it possible to form a bubble if there were no surface tension?

Relevant: "Are there any liquids with zero surface tension?".

Without surface tension to hold the liquid together, not only will the bubble pop but the liquid itself will become a cloud of gas, as surface tension is what allows liquid molecules to stick to each other instead of drifting off.

Thank you! Could you please explain why the bubble pops in a little more detail? I don't clearly understand what forces are acting on the liquid film and how surface tension helps to balance those forces and make the film stable.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
